# Perl/HTML Basic Login

Tags: html, perl, authentication, cgi

So I have a University assignment where I must have authenticated users login to edit a text file. I'm trying to contain this all within the one CGI file to keep it easy.

I've written a html form as shown below:

```
Admin Login: 
<form name="login" method="post" action="pbr.cgi"><input type="text" name="user" value="Username" onfocus="(this.value == 'Username') && (this.value = '')"onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Username')"/>  
<input type="password" name="password" value="123456" onfocus="(this.value == '123456') && (this.value = '')"onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = '123456')"/>  
<input class="login" name="Login" type="submit" value="Login"></form>
```

I also have a login sub in the cgi as below:

```
sub Login {
    $luser = $cgi->param('user');
    $lpass = $cgi->param('password');

    open (PASSWD, "<passwords.txt");
        my @passwds = <PASSWD>;
        close (PASSWD);

        foreach (@passwds){
            ($user, $pass, $passsalt) = split ":";
            if ($user = $luser){
                $testpass = $salt . $lpass;
                $testpass = sha256_hex($testpass);
                if ($pass = $testpass){
                    $validuser = 1;
                } else {
                    $validuser = 0;
                }

            } else {
                print "Failure!"
            }
        }
}
```

Can someone explain to me how I get the CGI to recognise the login button has been pressed and subsequently execute the Login sub while reloading the page? Obviously I'll have to set a cookie as well once I get this working but I just want to get it working first.

Comment: Not related to the question, but what that `onfocus="(this.value == '123456') && (this.value = '')"onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = '123456')"` for?

Comment: The onfocus removes the value from the field when clicked if its still set to default. The onblur on the otherhand will reset the field to default if no data is entered when you click out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The CGI module you're (obviously) using also supports [*fetching the parameter list as a hash*](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-4.28/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching_the_parameter_list_as_a_hash). You should try to dump this out to the see complete request:

```
print Dumper($cgi->Vars);
```

You'll notice that the `Login` button is a `<input ...>` tag like the others and behaves exactly the same way: By setting a parameter defined by the `name=` and `value=` properties.

Three additional remarks on your script:

1. `if ($user = $luser){` says: Try to copy the value of `$luser` into the variable `$user`. If this succeeds and the new value of `$user` is true (not `undef`, empty or `0`), run the following lines until end of the `if` block. `=` is an assignment in Perl, while `==` and `eq` are comparisons. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators for more information.
2. The better way of reading a file is using `while (<FILEHANDLE>) { ... }`. Your solution read the full file into memory even if the first line matches the user trying to login. `while` reads line-by-line until you exit the loop.
3. Consider running PerlCritic on your sourcecode. It doesn't check for errors, but shows *best practice* hints where the Perl community prefers some other way. Don't try to "fix" every critic report, but check them to improve your code.